# How to clone Umbraco Cloud development environment to local

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-cloud

I am currently in the process of migrating some old websites to Umbraco Cloud, however for testing it I created a brand new project, created a basic document type and added some text.

How do I extract the content from my Development Environment to Local?
The first time I started my local umbraco instance it asked to sync, downloaded some files and everything worked, however how do I trigger this for new changes?

I have tried the following in CMD in the /data/ folder:

```
echo > deploy
```

A file called "deploy-complete" is created but is empty, and new content did not download to local umbraco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was blind the first time.

In the local Umbraco Installation right-click the Home (or whatever node you want to sync to local) and click Restore or Partial Restore, this will trigger the sync.

Umbraco has a guide here:
https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Umbraco-Cloud/Deployment/Restoring-content/